# How to add the custom "when clause" in VS Code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, blazor, .net-core-3.0

Currently, I am developing a simple add-in for the .NET Core 3.0 blazor web projects. In this case, I want to enable the add-in if the .net core 3.0 blazor projects and if the project is not the .net core 3.0 blazor project, my custom add-in will not be shown.

I have googled regarding vscode add-in extension and found the default when clause for vscode like "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder" etc. But I want the add-in in workspace header with the condition like if the project is .net core 3.0 blazor. I don't know about how and where to add the logic for this.

[image]

I need to add my own condition for When clause to show my add-in. Also, If the project has my custom assemblies, I need to show another add-in in the explorer heading context menu with my own customized when clause.

Could you please suggest me how can I achieve this?

Below is my coding part:

**Package.Json**

```
"commands": [
            {
                "command": "extension.openTemplatesFolder",
                "title": "Open Templates Folder",
                "category": "Project"
            },
            {
                "command": "extension.saveProjectAsTemplate",
                "title": "Save Project as Template",
                "category": "Project"
            },
            {
                "command": "extension.deleteTemplate",
                "title": "Delete Existing Template",
                "category": "Project"
            },
            {
                "command": "extension.createProjectFromTemplate",
                "title": "Create Project from Template",
                "category": "Project"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "explorer/context": [
                {
                    "command": "extension.saveProjectAsTemplate",
                    "when": "myContext == success && explorerResourceIsRoot",
                    "group": "projectTemplates@1"
                }
            ]
        }
```

**extension.ts**

```
const value = "success";
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myContext', `${value}`);



export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {



    // create manager and initialize template folder
    let projectTemplatesPlugin = new ProjectTemplatesPlugin(context, vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('projectTemplates'));
    projectTemplatesPlugin.createTemplatesDirIfNotExists();

    // register commands



    // open templates folder
    let openTemplatesFolder = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.openTemplatesFolder', 
        OpenTemplatesFolderCommand.run.bind(undefined, projectTemplatesPlugin));
    context.subscriptions.push(openTemplatesFolder);

    // save as template
    let saveProjectAsTemplate = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.saveProjectAsTemplate', 
        SaveProjectAsTemplateCommand.run.bind(undefined, projectTemplatesPlugin));
    context.subscriptions.push(saveProjectAsTemplate);
}
```

**Note:**

The `vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myContext', value);` is not executed before show the add-in. It was executed after click the add-in

Comment: Included the code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `setContext` command for this:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myContext', `value`);
```

Then use `myContext` in your `when` clauses.

This command is not currently well documented but here's [an example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/349e31fee9603711ddabfe4c8cb6fb66b72e28f3/extensions/git/src/main.ts#L43) usage of this command in the git extension

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but, I can't achieve what i need. I have an extension source with the common extension.ts file. I have added the below code in this file
 

vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'sample', '${count}');
 
Then, I have used the "sample" in my package.json file. I want to enable my add-in when the count is 1. So I have added the below code in packages.json file
 
"when" : "sample == 1"
 
But, this code is not working for me. Could you please suggest to me what I did wrong.

Comment: Please find the code from attachment. https://srv-file4.gofile.io/download/Ol0VZv/vscode-project-templates.zip

Comment: I can't download that file. Update your original question to include the code for a minimum example extension that doesn't work

Comment: Binerner - I have updated (edited) the code snippet in the above actual query for your reference. Please check this and share your thoughts to proceed further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see the code snippet i have updated and share your suggestions.

Comment: I have uploaded the source again. Please try the below link now and let me know if you face any problem in download this. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqRHVcpXhN1DegqhZHT_dUA5hSU?e=SqEtW9

Comment: I placed the command vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'extensionSelectionmode',true) in extension.ts file which is using for register the vscode commands. Later, used this extensionSelectionmode in the when clause which is in package.json file for enable the add-in. But "extensionSelectionmode" value is not set. So, my add-in is not shown in the vscode explorer context. Where will I place setContext command vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'extensionSelectionmode',true) to return the extensionSelectionmode value as true to show my add-in (when right click on workspace).